# Angular: Cannot declare 'MatToolbar' in an NgModule as it's not a part of the current compilation

Tags: angular, layout, module, routes

```
    import { MatToolbarModule, MatToolbar } from '@angular/material/toolbar';
import { MatIconModule, MatIcon } from '@angular/material/icon'; 
import { Routes, RouterModule, RouterOutlet } from '@angular/router';
import { MainLayoutComponent } from './main/main.layout.component'

@NgModule({ 
    declarations: [ MainLayoutComponent ],
    imports: [
        MatIconModule,
        MatToolbarModule,
        RouterModule,
    ],
    exports: [ 
        MainLayoutComponent
    ]
})
export class LayoutModule {

}
```

The above code is my module to hold all different layout components.

In my app.routing.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
 
import { MainLayoutComponent} from '../../shared/layouts/main/main.layout.component'
import { HomeComponent } from '../home/pages/home.component';
import { LayoutModule } from '../../shared/layouts/layouts.module';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', 
    component: MainLayoutComponent, 
    children: [
      { path: '', component: HomeComponent }
    ] 
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [LayoutModule, RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

i started having errors and one error is below

> Cannot declare 'MatToolbar' in an NgModule as it's not a part of the
> current compilation.
>
> > 

I use mat-toolbar tag in the my main layout file. I have no clue what setting I go wrong.